# converting a list to a dict with the last element in the list will be the value and the rest will be the key

Tags: python

I have a list of items, for example:

```
items = ['BANANA', 'FRIES', 12]
```

I want items[-1] to be the value of a dict and the rest will be the key like:

```
dict = {'BANANA FRIES': 12}
```

I want a piece of code that does it for any list of any length so that the last element is the value and the rest will be the key.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. It will work for any length of `list`:

```
items = ['BANANA', 'FRIES', 12]
di = {}
di[' '.join([item for item in items[:-1]])] = items[-1]
print(di)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{' '.join(items[:-1]): items[-1]}
```

Comment: WOW it's powerful!
can you explain the line to me?

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way to do this:

```
my_list = ['BANANA', 'FRIES', 12]
my_dict = { ' '.join(my_list[:-1]) : my_list[-1] }
```

## Doing this task with a function:

```
def convertToDict(my_list):
    return { ' '.join(my_list[:-1]) : my_list[-1] }

items = ['BANANA', 'FRIES', 12]
items_dict = convertToDict(items)
print(items_dict)
```

**Result:** { 'BANANA FRIES': 12 }

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

`{" ".join(items[:-1]): items[-1]}`